# Add `proguard` and failed authentication service

Tags: android, web-services, proguard, shrink

I am new in `proguard` and shrink code and resource. I have some problems in this topic and searched but can't find any resources. I want to add `proguard` to my application then i added below code to my `gradle`. In my application, i have a login page that get username and password and sent to server with `gson` and `JsonObject`. after add `proguard`, i can't connect to server and failed without any errors. what? What is my problem? I check the value returns from server in debug mode, shows, a.b.c.d , i think that convert to obfuscation class but not recognized.

my gradle:

> ```
>  buildTypes{
>    /* release{
>         minifyEnabled true
>         shrinkResources true
>        *//* proguardFiles getIsDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'*//*
>     }*/
>     debug{
>         minifyEnabled true
>         shrinkResources true
>         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
>                 'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
>                 'proguard.cfg'
>     }
> }
> ```

I add some parts to `proguard` configs, because before i had some errors. The `proguard.cfg`:

```
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
  ##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature
 # For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*
 # Gson specific classes
 -keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
 #-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
 # Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
 -keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
 ##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

Answer (score 1):

try to >>  -Keep public com.test.LoginParam

Answer (score 0):

try-->-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }

Comment: Thanks for your reply but not changed anything. The service again failed after add this.

Answer (score 0):

you must prevent your model class use in login method to being obfuscate
-keep class your model_class_with_package_name.** { *; }